# How can I create a string array of values pulled from a struct in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I have a MATLAB struct that I would like to pull a single text field from every entry and put these entries into a string array.  An example struct can be created with the following:

```
allFiles = dir(fullfile('C:\Users\username\Documents))
```

The above returns a structure array where each file is an entry with the fields "name", "folder", "date", etc.
If I call `allFiles.name`, I get each filename entry as a separate answer.  It looks like

```
ans = 
    'exampleFile1.txt'
ans = 
    'exampleFile2.txt'
```

Alternatively, I can call `[allFiles.name]` and this simply concatenates the character arrays as follows

```
'exampleFile1.txtexampleFile2.txt'
```

The only solution I've found is to iterate through the list

```
filesArray = []
for k=1:length(allFiles)
    filesArray = [filesArray string(allFiles(k).name)]
end
```

and this returns a proper string array `["exampleFile1.txt" "exampleFile2.txt"]`.

Is there a more elegant solution to extract these entries directly into a string array without iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can collect all names in a cell array.

```
allNames = {allFiles.name};
```

Then to turn this into a string array, just do

```
allNames = string({allFiles.name});
```